# Basic Combination: How many unique combinations* of four 3-sided die?

Tags: probability, combinations, dice

I have four dice. Each die has 3 sides. I want to know the total amount of unique combinations*.

```
Die1,Die2,Die3,Die4
1,1,1,1
2,1,1,1
3,1,1,1
1,2,1,1
1,3,1,1
2,2,1,1
2,3,1,1
3,2,1,1
Etc....
```

- I don’t know if combinations is the right word, because I know this has a specific math meaning.

The only way I know how to solve this problem, is to draw a picture, but that takes too long. I want a formula that I can use to calculate the total amount of unique combinations. I don’t think the binomial formula will work, because I have 4 separate dice.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  You have $3$ possibilities for the first die, $3$ for the second, $3$ for the third, and $3$ for the fourth -- altogether $3^4=81$; by the way, *die* is singular and *dice* is plural

Comment: Does the order of the dice matter, or do you want to count distinct selections of faces?  (Is `3211` distinguished from `1231` or not?)

Answer (score 0):

You have $4$ dice, each of which have $3$ sides. So there is three possible outcomes for each die. Hence total $3^4=81$ different outcomes possible for $4$ dice.
The word $permutation$ is more accurate here than $combination$, since here the order of outcome is relevant, i.e., $1232$ is different from $1322$. Whereas in combination the ordering is not relevant.